# What is Linux equivalent of LPTSTR & LPCSTR?

Tags: c, linux, porting, lpcstr, lptstr

I am converting windows library to linux. I need to find LPTSTR and LPCSTR in linux.

I get to know that i can use wchar_t can be used but I am not really sure about using it.

one of the method that uses LPTSTR is as follows:

```
void ErrorExit(LPTSTR zFunction)
{
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you are working in C, you will get compilation errors with wchar_t.  It will work with C++ but not that on Windows wchar_t is 2 bytes; on Linux it is 4 bytes.

Comment: @cup When was `wchar_t` removed from C? As far as I know, it exists in C.

Comment: @glglgl: I don't know if it was removed from C.  It doesn't work on C programs in gcc 4.7.2.  Works on Windows.

Comment: @cup Good that my gcc doesn't know this: `#include <stdlib.h>` // `int main() { wchar_t w; }` works here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Linux you don't usually use `wchar_t` for library API functions. Most libraries use UTF-8 encoded strings, so they take as strings plain arrays of NUL-terminated chars (IMO that is far better than duplicating all the functions with ANSI and Unicode versions).

So, with that in mind:

- `LPCTSTR`, `LPCSTR`, `LPCWSTR` -> `const char *`.
- `LPTSTR`, `LPSTR`, `LPWSTR` -> `char *`.

If you insist in using Unicode functions, MS style, you have to be aware that they actually use UTF-16 encoded strings, and `wchar_t` is not a portable type, as its size is not specified by the language. Instead you can use `uint16_t`:

- `LPCWSTR` -> `const uint16_t *`.
- `LPWSTR` -> `uint16_t *`.

And if you want to be extra MS compatible, you can use the `UNICODE` macro to conditionally typedef the `LPTSTR` and `LPTCSTR` into one of the others, but that's probably unneeded for your problem.

Comment: IBTD. Most libraries use just plain strings. Whether they are encoded in UTF-8 or in latin1 or in whatever is subject to the locale settings. If you need converting, you can take [`mbtowc()` et al.](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51B_HTML/MAN/MAN3/2461____.HTM)

Comment: @glglgl: Well, the _most_ part is arguably. But _most_ modern Linux distributions use UTF-8 locale by default (and little reason to change it), and _quite a few_ high level libraries (see GTK, Qt, Pango, Cairo...) use UTF-8  regardless of the configured locale.

Answer (score 5):

LPTSTR - L‌ong P‌ointer to T‌CHAR STR‌ing (Don't worry, a long pointer is the same as a pointer.)

LPCSTR - L‌ong P‌ointer to a C‌onst  STR‌ing

```
LPSTR = char*
LPCSTR = const char*
LPWSTR = wchar_t*
LPCWSTR = const wchar_t*
LPTSTR = char* or wchar_t* depending on _UNICODE
LPCTSTR = const char* or const wchar_t* depending on _UNICODE
```

[from msn page LPCSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230350.aspx)

```
typedef const char* LPCSTR;
```

[from msn page LPTSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)=>

```
#ifdef UNICODE
 typedef LPWSTR LPTSTR;
#else
 typedef LPSTR LPTSTR;
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort +1

Comment: explaining the acronym alone justifies the +1